# Entities.Find(id) can't get updated data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two web, using same EF and EfRepository(like nopcommerce), I changed the data in web 1, and updated by SaveChanges().

like:
t.status =200;  //old is 10

_context.SaveChanges()

But in web 2, I use Entities.Find(id) to get same data,  I got the recorder unchanged.

like:

this.Entities.Find(2);

t.status is 10, but it is 200 in database.

How I fix it? thanks.

Comment: Are you using a single `DbContext` instance across the entire application? If so, data for entities which have already been loaded will not be updated to match the new values returned from the database. **NB:** This is most definitely the wrong thing to do for ASP.NET; you should have one `DbContext` instance per request - in DI terms, it should be `Scoped`, not `Singleton`.

Comment: `Find` will return a cached object if possible. That's probably what happens here. And it indicates you have DbContext that lives too long (see the comment above).